# MySQL Remove everything before third /

Tags: mysql

I am trying to remove everything before the third / in a column. For example: If there is a URL in the coloumn such as

http://www.example.com/example1/example2?=testest123

I would like to remove everything (not including the thrid slash) so i will be left with something like this

/example1/example2?=testest123

I have tried using this but it only removes everything from first "/" and i can't work out how to get it to count to the third then remove.

```
update table 
       set column2 = substring(column1, instr(column1, '/') + 1);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't this be the fourth slash in this case?

Answer (score 1):

To start, you can use the [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function to get the characters of the string leading up to the third (or fourth slash, in your example) like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, '/', 4)
FROM myTable;
```

You can use the [`REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function to remove that substring by replacing it with an empty string, like this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(val, SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, '/', 4), '')
FROM myTable;
```

Now, to update your table, simple rewrite the query to set the value to the one above:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET val = REPLACE(val, SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, '/', 4), '');
```

**NOTE** that if there are less than four occurrences of a forward slash, `SUBSTRING_INDEX` will return the entire string, and therefore completely replacing the entire string by an empty value so you should be very careful when preforming this update.

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e25e/1) example with your sample text, and one that I wrote with fewer slashes to demonstrate the last point.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit messy, but you can try this :

```
UPDATE table 
SET column2 = SUBSTRING(column1, 
                        LOCATE('/', column1, 
                            LOCATE('/', column1,                        
                                LOCATE('/', column1))+1)+1)
```